# How to clone a googlecode mercurial repository in jenkins

Tags: mercurial, hudson, jenkins, google-code

I am having a problem to trigger a repository clone of googlecode project.

I keep receiving the following error:

Started by user anonymous $ hg clone
--rev default "https://username@demo.projectname.googlecode.com/hg/ " "F:\Hudson\jobs\project Demostration project\workspace" abort: demo.projectname.googlecode.com certificate error: certificate is for
*.googlecode.com, googlecode.com, *.codespot.com, *.googlesource.com, googlesource.com (use --insecure to connect insecurely) ERROR: Failed to clone.
--template {node}

Anyone know on how to tell jenkins it is safe to use that certificate? **In what textbox do you place --insecure option**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a relatively new command line option (1.8.3 I think) to get around a relatively new practice of actually checking certificates (1.8.2 I think).  It's likely not exposed in the Jenkins UI.  Some things you could do to work around it:

- put the server's cert's fingerprint in a whitelist in your (Jenkin's user's) hgrc
- wrap Mercurial in a quick shell script that passes --insecure
- clone from the non-https version of the google URL (I think they still allow that)
- configure the CACerts for Mercurial either globally (`/etc/mercurial/hgrc`) or in the Jenkins user's `~/.hgrc`

Any of those should work and most of them are explained here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates